# UWP Xbox App: Style issue

Tags: windows, xaml, win-universal-app, xbox-one

Okay so with the UWP support for Xbox being released recently I decided to have a go deploying and testing my existing app on my Xbox. It works great with zero changes aside from one minor but really off-putting issue.

For arguments sake lets say I'm using a listview in my app, rather than using the style you get with say a mouse over each item in the list the controller seems to act like it is tabbing to highlight the selected item which surround the item with a black and white border (which is completely out with the style of app).

I have done a search and cant see anybody else with this issue so far, and have tried experimenting but I cannot for the life of me see any way to customize this so does anybody know of a way to remove this border or at the very least style it?

Comment: Set `UseSystemFocusVisuals=False` for the ListViewItem, it's hard set to True on a setter in the Style template for `ListViewItem`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.usesystemfocusvisuals.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some more digging and a watch of this great session video from build (https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B883) it seems that the "Marching ants" as they call them will be removed in a future update.